# CSS: Make a block element fill the entire space of a parent element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a link in a `<th>` element and have the `<a>` element fill the entire space of the `<th>`. While I can get it to fille horizontally with width:100%, getting it to fill vertically is proving to be troublesome. height:100% seems to have no effect.

I want to do this so that the user can click anywhere in the cell to activate the link. I know I could put an onClick property on the `<th>` itself and handle it via javascript, but I would like to do it the "proper" css way.

**Clarification:** Each row of the table can have a different height because the content is dynamic, so solutions that use a fixed height for the `<a>` or `<th>` elements will not work.

Here is some sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">
th {
  font-size: 50%;
  width: 20em;
  line-height: 100%;
}
th a {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
th a:hover {
  background-color: #333
}
</style>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th><a href="foo">Link 1</a></th>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dapibus tortor.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><a href="foo">Link 2</a></th>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dapibus tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dapibus tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dapibus tortor. </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[And here is a page with that exact same code](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/26620/stackoverflow1.html)

As you can see if you mouseover the link, the `<a>` element is not filling vertically which produces an awkward look. I could fix the hover background by putting it in a "**th:hover a**" style, but the link would still only actually function if you clicked where the actual `a` tag is.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just change th style to this

```
th {
  font-size: 50%;
  width: 20em;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%; 
}
```

cheers

Comment: just add a height with 100% ;)

Comment: be sure to test this in IE6 due to it's inability to process 100% relative values properly...

Comment: Luckily this is for an internal tool where I can just punch anyone using IE6. :)

Comment: Oh and thank you gonxalo! That was surprisingly easy. Firebug had me believing that the th was already filling the entire space but I guess there is a difference between visibly filling it and filling it for the purposes of children's relative sizes.

Comment: IMPORTANT: I just spent some time discovering that this answer as presented actually doesn't work when a proper DOCTYPE is set on the document. It only works in quirks mode. The fix is simple: The `<tr>` element must ALSO have height:100%.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution (including a height on the <tr>) only works in quirks mode in  IE6/7/8 and Opera, and doesn't work at all in Safari (and Chrome).

Answer (score 3):

As [@Hober](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546946/css-make-a-block-element-fill-the-entire-space-of-a-parent-element/546986#546986) says, you need to give the `<th>` a height.  You could also use `height: 100%` there.

If you know the dimensions of your `<th>`, which it looks like you probably won't in this case (since they're on the side), I've had luck adding a padding to push the `<a>` out to the edges (past any padding from the `<th>` itself), and then bringing it back in with a corresponding negative margin.  Like this:

```
th a{
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: -10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest i got was this...

```
th {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 50%;
  width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
}
th a {
  display: table; /* or block, up to you */
  margin: none;
  width:100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 20%;
}
```

But it makes all your rows the same height. Maybe someone else can fix that if it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `<th>` a height, so that your style block will end up something like

```
th {
  font-size: 50%;
  width: 20em;
  height: 8ex;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

Edit: Actually, for height you should probably use a vertical measure like "ex", instead of a horizontal measure of "em". Example changed to reflect that.

Comment: The problem is that the height of each row in the table needs to be dynamic. And even if you do set the height, the content is going to resize based on the width of the browser so you can't depend on it being an exact height.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you can set the HEIGHT of your "a" element in pixels instead of percentage.

If you specify a percentage, 100% will end up being the height of the TEXT itself.

A pixel height will give you a static height, and will work for this situation.

```
td a {height: 100px;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the height of each table row will vary based on the content, and I do not want each row to be at a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript (see below).

```
<style type="text/css">
th {
font-size: 50%;
width: 20em;
background-color: #aaa;

}
.off {
background-color: #aaa;
}
.on {
background-color: #333
}


<th onmouseover="this.className='on'" onmouseout="this.className='off'">><a href="foo">Link 1</a></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

The th element needs to have a height assigned to it.  Giving it a height of 100% should cause the element to expand to the height of its container (i.e. the height of the row).  This may not work properly in IE 6, you may try adding `_height: 1%` to address IE6 - I don't have IE6 to test this with, but I tested in Firefox and it appears to be doing what you want.

```
th {
  height: 100%;
}
```