# How to fill the anchor element's height to 100% in html?

Tags: html, css

I have created a top bar that have `height: 50px`, then an anchor element inside it, the anchor element with it's padding supposed to be exact as the top bar height.

Testing the code in major browsers, *Firefox* has given the exact pixels height of top bar to anchor element, but in *Chrome* and *IE*, it have -1px result.
[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4YQtA/)

HTML:

```
<div > <a href="">Text Here</a> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
}
a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px; /* Adjusting this would affect element block size */
    color: white;
    font-family:'Bebas Neue';
    background-color: #777;
}
a:hover { background-color: green; }
```

**How could I fill the dimensions of the `<a>` anchor element up to the div's height?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As no one seems to have shown you the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) css property: Add the following to your `<a>`

```
height:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

**EDIT**:

- To vertically align the content: Use `display table-cell` on the `<a>` element and `display: table` on its parent.

```css
div {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}
a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: table;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  background-color: #777;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a > span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href=""><span>Text Here</span></a> 
</div>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4YQtA/9/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but box-sizing does not work pretty well on Firefox, it does well on Chrome and IE... I tried the Fiddle on those browsers...

Comment: box sizing should work on all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing.  If you are using an older version of firefox you will need to add the moz suffix

Comment: oh I see, I not familiar with that yet & responsive design, but I hope to learn it sooner, the site you linked is useful, really.

Comment: Sir for instance I have a `32px` `font-size` is there a way to make the element vertically-centered using box-sizing?

Comment: This technique is really something useful!, cause it centers itself vertically, Is there an disadvantage of using these? I mean, it is not semantically a table...

Comment: the only disadvantage is that it won't work in IE7 or earlier, however I always says punish the stupid ie users!

Comment: @Martijn - the ie7 warning was valid at the time - 2014.  If you are going to remove that, then remove the moz suffix too as this is now fully supported in all modern browsers

Comment: Haha you are completely correct, guess the old disliking of IE was a bit stronger. Also took the css `-moz` prefix out of the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the another way :-

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/4YQtA/3/

```
a {
    height: 30px;/*changes here*/
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    font-family:'Bebas Neue';
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Comment: I use preferably `height: 100%` so that I won't have to worry about `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` differences from the topbar dimension, but this code is ideal for fixed container values.

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
}
a {
    padding: 0 10px;    
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I prefer percentages for `line-height` values.

Comment: but % take more memory cache rather than fixed height

Comment: Oh, that's something new to me, I'm new to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The technique I have found is to use `0` `padding` on top and bottom for the `<a>` element then use `height: 100%` to fill the height dimension and just use `line-height: 200%` to adjust the text.

Change these CSS properties to:

```
a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 200%;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4YQtA/1/)

Comment: Please answer if there's a better way.

Comment: Nope, display: block or inline-block and setting it's height to 100% pretty much does the trick.

Comment: @Ruddy Sir, You have been a member for 10 months without noticing  this? blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions

Comment: @Daniel Oh dear, right lets see. You asked a questions full well knowing the answer. There are a **ton** of questions asking pretty much the same thing so why not try to use the search bar? If you want to know if there is a better way you should add what you think into the question, not create an answer a mere 50 seconds after posting a question. If you had posted this and not many people got back to you then you found a way to do it, then by all means add it as an answer and I'm sure you will get up voted for it.

Comment: Sir, I've searched and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546946/css-make-a-block-element-fill-the-entire-space-of-a-parent-element but there's nothing such as to filling the anchor element's height to 100%, if there is, please link here so I can see it, I'm a newbie in HTML, as of I've read in the "
It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions" It's said that "if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later" please correct me if have misunderstood anything.

Comment: This answer is Pretty Cool Dude